# Sandbox Visual Webpart Not Adding BulletedList Control

Tags: sandbox-solution, visual-web-part

I have a sandbox visual webpart (got it by installing SharePoint Power Tools) and in that I have a "Place Holder" control named "phMsg". I am adding a "BulletedList" control to that place holder in page prerender event.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    phMsg.Controls.Add(msg.MsgList);
}
```

The list of messages (bulleted list items) is not shown on page.

I am sure the control "BulletedList" has items (messages).

Please help!

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the control to ascx file before using it in code so that it get initiated.